# Ordering archive block

Tags: 6, views, blocks

I've upgraded an installation from Drupal 5 to Drupal 6, and now I can't get the archive to be displayed in the right order. I've set the sort criteria of the block to be descending and in the preview I can see it correctly: on top I get the last entry, followed by the one after that, etc. The block displayed in the left-hand column never changes, even after cleaning the cache. I know this is the right block because if I remove it, the archive view on the left column will go away too.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Which modules did you install? As far as I remember, a Drupal site without third-party modules doesn't have a "archive" block. For example, Views has an archive view, which can be a block too.

Comment: That could very well be it. Its a view that gets displayed as a page and as a block. [This](https://drupal.org/node/290904) seemed to be the most promising thing but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It must have been some sort of caching issue, because the link above just worked.

Comment: Must wait 2 days.. :/